# Regex funciona em testador online mas não funciona no meu site em javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

[Link do site onde testei o regex](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95006)

Testo no site e funciona correctamente o objectivo é ter 2 numeros como coordenadas 12.0,34.0  e receber a resposta válida mas estou a receber no meu log invalida.

```
var string = "12.0,34.0";
    var re = new RegExp("[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+))?");
    if (re.test(string)) {
        console.log("Valida");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalida");
    }
```

Relembrando o que aparece no meu console é invalid ! ja testei com outras expressões mais simples e funciona perfeitamente o código se alguem souber a solução é que eu pouco ou nada sei sobre regex

Comment: As strings que estás a testar podem ter lixo ou só numeros + virgula + numeros e o que precisas é saber se é uma coordenada válida?

Comment: só numeros com . e uma virgula o regex não estava correcto mas agora já o modifiquei e está tudo a funcionar bem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tira as aspas. Tenta o seguinte:

```
var string = "12.0,34.0";
var re = new RegExp(/[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+))?/);
if (re.test(string)) {
  console.log("Valida");
} else {
  console.log("Invalida");
}
```

[Testei](https://jsfiddle.net/kp1omcu5/4/) agora, e deu como Valida

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado, pode me explicar porque que o meu metodo é errado ?

Comment: Sinceramente nunca usei `RegExp` assim. Vou fazer uns testes e já lhe digo aqui se descobrir algo

Comment: Na realidade o teu também funciona, o problema eram as aspas. Tenta assim: `new RegExp(/[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+))?/);`

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que a string que tens já está formatada e precisas só de saber se é válida ou não, a melhor maneira não é RegExp mas sim uma verificação numérica. Tendo em conta que os limites são:

```
Latitude (S-N):   -90 to  +90  
Longitude (O-E): -180 to +180
```

podes fazer assim:

```
function verificador(str) {
    var coords = str.split(',').map(Number);
    var validos = coords.filter(function(coord, i) {
        return Math.abs(coord) <= 90 + (90 * i);
    });
    return validos.length == 2 ? coords : false;
};

console.log(verificador("30.02")); // false
console.log(verificador("30.02,-100.876")); // [30.02, -100.876]
console.log(verificador("330.02,-100.876")); // false
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v0agez4n/